# Filemaker not recognizing Applescript command during loop

Tags: loops, applescript, containers, paste, filemaker

I'm getting an odd result from an Applescript script being called from within Filemaker that I've not seen before nor have I found a reference to it online here or elsewhere.

The following script creates three new records and makes a call to the Filemaker script "paste_into_container". The FM script "paste_into_container is very simple, it pastes whatever is on the clipboard into a specific container field. When the script is called from within Filemaker, the "paste_into"container" subscript will only paste the contents of the clipboard into the last new record. The container field on the first two records is left blank.

It's almost as if the loop creates the new record, ignores the "paste_into_container" script, and then moves on to the next iteration of the loop.

The script works fine when called from ScriptEditor but fails when called from within Filemaker. The script will also work if I drop the repeat loop and create just one record.

I've tried increasing the delay added at the end of each loop but it does not make any difference whether it is 1 or 5 seconds.

I'm sure it's something simple but I'm not seeing it and after two days it's time for help (of one kind or another)

additional info:
Mac OS 10.6.8
FM 11 running through FM11 server

Thanks in advance

Phil

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro"
 show every record in table "Image_Info" in database myDB
    repeat with i from 1 to 3
            go to layout 1 of database myDB
            set myNewRecord to create new record in database myDB
            go to last record
            do script "paste_into_container" 
            delay 1
    end repeat  
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a very good discussion on another forum specifically about this problem. When FM moved from FM10 to FM11 they changed how the program handled requests from imbedded applescripts. Essentially, since FM11 Filemaker treats Applescript commands asynchronously rather than synchoronously whenever the Applescript calls on an internal Filemaker script with the do script command. What this means is that Filemaker will allow the Applescript to continue without waiting for feedback from Filemaker saying the internal FM script is complete. There is a work around but it is hardly elegant and does not seem universal. See link below.

As I understand it this only affects embedded Applescripts calling on other local Filemaker scripts.

[link](http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/4b2544f7a4?page=2)